# Extracting information from HTML using CLASS_NAME attribute

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to extract a table from html using selenium. My intention is capture  the all class "iframe-b3", because I need the date and the values in the table.

https://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/servicos-de-dados/market-data/consultas/boletim-diario/boletim-diario-do-mercado/

"Tabela: Participação dos Investidores"
Code trials:

```
driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="iframe-b3")
print_tabela = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="iframe-b3")
```

I need to copy this informations and transcript to Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find the table on the [website](https://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/servicos-de-dados/market-data/consultas/boletim-diario/boletim-diario-do-mercado/). However the datepicker element is within an  [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *presence_of_element_located*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/servicos-de-dados/market-data/consultas/boletim-diario/boletim-diario-do-mercado/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.iframe-b3")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.duet-date input[name='date']"))).get_attribute("value"))
    driver.quit()
    ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  2023-02-07
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)